# How to preserve the order of an array of objects manipulated from my state upon the execution of functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing an Issue on the navigation function of a form I am building.

The below and linked code is the dummiest version possible to try an shorten and simplify the issue.

I will post my whole code below and you can run it [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-state-bug-lsehi?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) as well.

It's a form that the user fills and navigates from step to step until the final submission of the data.

The navigation buttons work well, using `this.inputMenuNavigationHandler`(`App.js Line: 25`), going from section to section, but on a specific section I have created kind of sub-sections, which are alternated using `this.subOptionNavigation` `function`.

When I alternate the info inside `case "foo2"`(`switch function` of `Input.js` - `line: 15`) and afterwards call `this.inputMenuNavigationHandler` again, for some reason the sections get out of order, and instead of navigating from `secondMenu` to `thirdMenu`, it takes me to `firstMenu`.

I do not understand why this is happening, as the navigation function, which uses the `classArray.indexOf(classElement)`, in other words, the order of the `array` of `objects`, does not interfere or relates to what the `value` of `this.state.newClassForm.secondMenu.internalNavigation` is...

**App.js File**

```
import React from "react";
import Input from "./Input";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    classNavigation: "firstMenu",
    newClassForm: {
      firstMenu: {
        elementType: "foo1",
        title: "First Section"
      },
      secondMenu: {
        elementType: "foo2",
        title: "Second Section",
        internalNavigation: "tba"
      },
      thirdMenu: {
        elementType: "foo3",
        title: "Third Section"
      }
    }
  };

  inputMenuNavigationHandler = (classArray, classElement, command) => {
    let index = classArray.indexOf(classElement);
    if (command === "increment" && index < classArray.length - 1) {
      let incrementModal = classArray[index + 1].id;
      this.setState(({ classNavigation, ...restTop }) => ({
        classNavigation: incrementModal,
        ...restTop
      }));
    }
    if (command === "decrement" && index > 0) {
      let decrementModal = classArray[index - 1].id;
      this.setState(({ classNavigation, ...restTop }) => ({
        classNavigation: decrementModal,
        ...restTop
      }));
    }
  };

  subOptionNavigation = childSubOption => {
    this.setState(
      ({
        newClassForm: {
          secondMenu: { internalNavigation, ...restSecondMenu },
          ...restNewClassForm
        },
        ...restTop
      }) => ({
        newClassForm: {
          secondMenu: { internalNavigation: childSubOption, ...restSecondMenu },
          ...restNewClassForm
        },
        ...restTop
      })
    );
  };

  render() {
    let classArray = [];
    for (let key in { ...this.state.newClassForm }) {
      classArray.push({
        id: key,
        config: this.state.newClassForm[key]
      });
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {classArray.map(cl =>
          cl.id.indexOf(this.state.classNavigation) !== -1 ? (
            <div
              key={cl.id}
              style={{
                padding: "10px",
                border: "1px solid black",
                margin: "5px"
              }}
            >
              <Input
                classArray={classArray}
                classElement={cl}
                elementType={cl.config.elementType}
                title={cl.config.title}
                navigationIncrement={() =>
                  this.inputMenuNavigationHandler(classArray, cl, "increment")
                }
                navigationDecrement={() =>
                  this.inputMenuNavigationHandler(classArray, cl, "decrement")
                }
                internalNavigationDisplay={
                  this.state.newClassForm.secondMenu.internalNavigation
                }
                toOption1={() => this.subOptionNavigation("subOption1")}
                toOption2={() => this.subOptionNavigation("subOption2")}
              />
            </div>
          ) : null
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Input.js**

```
import React from "react";

export default function Input(props) {
  let input = null;
  switch (props.elementType) {
    case "foo1":
      input = (
        <div>
          <div>{props.title}</div>
          <button onClick={props.navigationDecrement}>Previous</button>
          <button onClick={props.navigationIncrement}>Next</button>
        </div>
      );
      break;
    case "foo2":
      input = (
        <div>
          {props.internalNavigationDisplay === "tba" ? (
            <div>
              <div>{props.title}</div>
              <button onClick={props.toOption1}>Option 1</button>
              <button onClick={props.toOption2}>Option 2</button>
            </div>
          ) : null}
          {props.internalNavigationDisplay === "subOption1" ? (
            <div>
              <div>SubOption 1</div>
              <button onClick={props.navigationDecrement}>Previous</button>
              <button onClick={props.navigationIncrement}>Next</button>
            </div>
          ) : null}
          {props.internalNavigationDisplay === "subOption2" ? (
            <div>
              <div>SubOption 2</div>
              <button onClick={props.navigationDecrement}>Previous</button>
              <button onClick={props.navigationIncrement}>Next</button>
            </div>
          ) : null}
        </div>
      );
      break;
    case "foo3":
      input = (
        <div>
          <div>{props.title}</div>
          <button onClick={props.navigationDecrement}>Previous</button>
          <button onClick={props.navigationIncrement}>Next</button>
        </div>
      );
      break;
    default:
      input = null;
  }
  return { ...input };
}
```

Comment: I have been trying to figure it our on my own. I think that there is something happening to the part of the code at ```inputMenuNavigationHandler``` which corresponds to the ```index``` of the instance I am navigating to. I have changed some stuff at the ```codesandbox``` link trying to somehow preserve the index, but it does not work anyway... Really crazy what is going on here

Comment: I am not managing to preserve ```let index = classArray.indexOf(classElement);``` when I navigate into the sub sections of ```secondMenu```. I can see it clearly now. I am now trying to preserve it.

Comment: well, this issue leads me to think that I need to do something with the ```classArray``` variable located in the ```render()``` block. Somehow, when the component renders and mounts, this is screwing the order of index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could also preserve my array of manipulated objects in order to keep the array on the same order just by using a lifecycle hook:

moving the code from the `render` part, and storing in my `state`, and then rendering this `state` on `input` in order to run my logic, it works as well.

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("component did mount");
    let classArray = [];
    for (let key in { ...this.state.newClassForm }) {
      classArray.push({
        id: key,
        config: this.state.newClassForm[key]
      });
    }
    this.setState(
      ({ newClassArray, ...restTop }) => ({
        newClassArray: classArray,
        ...restTop
      }),
      () => console.log(this.state.newClassArray)
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well!!!

Here is my solution in order to preserve the `index`

I have created a button, which will start the navigation:

```
 <div className="App">
        <h1>Create a new class?</h1>
        <button onClick={this.newClassHandler}>Go!!</button>
        {this.state.createNewClass
          ? this.state.newClassArray.map //...map the stuff and render the input sections
```

So on the `newClassHandler` function I move the code that once was in my `render` part of the component, which was the reason why the index was getting screwed up, as some bug may happen when I navigate into the sub section of the second `input`, once the component re renders.

Does any one have a solution which does not require the use of `state`???

```
import React from "react";
import Input from "./Input";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    indexOfNavigation: 0,
    createNewClass: false,
    newClassArray: [],
    classNavigation: "firstMenu",
    newClassForm: {
      firstMenu: {
        elementType: "foo1",
        title: "First Section"
      },
      secondMenu: {
        elementType: "foo2",
        title: "Second Section",
        internalNavigation: "tba"
      },
      thirdMenu: {
        elementType: "foo3",
        title: "Third Section"
      }
    }
  };

  newClassHandler = () => {
    let classArray = [];
    for (let key in { ...this.state.newClassForm }) {
      classArray.push({
        id: key,
        config: this.state.newClassForm[key]
      });
    }
    this.setState(({ createNewClass, newClassArray, ...restTop }) => ({
      createNewClass: true,
      newClassArray: classArray,
      ...restTop
    }));
  };

  inputMenuNavigationHandler = (classArray, classElement, command) => {
    let index = classArray.indexOf(classElement);
    console.log("index before setting my state", index);
    console.log("element Id before navigating - ", classElement.id);
    this.setState(
      ({ indexOfNavigation, ...restTop }) => ({
        indexOfNavigation: index,
        ...restTop
      }),
      () => {
        if (
          command === "increment" &&
          this.state.indexOfNavigation < classArray.length - 1
        ) {
          this.setState(
            ({ indexOfNavigation, ...restTop }) => ({
              indexOfNavigation: indexOfNavigation + 1,
              ...restTop
            }),
            () => {
              console.log(
                "index after setting state",
                this.state.indexOfNavigation
              );
              let incrementModal = classArray[this.state.indexOfNavigation].id;
              this.setState(
                ({ classNavigation, ...restTop }) => ({
                  classNavigation: incrementModal,
                  ...restTop
                }),
                () => {
                  console.log(
                    "element Id being received after navigating",
                    classElement.id
                  );
                  console.log(
                    "classNavigation info after navigating",
                    this.state.classNavigation
                  );
                }
              );
            }
          );
        }
        if (command === "decrement" && this.state.indexOfNavigation > 0) {
          this.setState(
            ({ indexOfNavigation, ...restTop }) => ({
              indexOfNavigation: indexOfNavigation - 1,
              ...restTop
            }),
            () => {
              console.log(
                "index after setting state",
                this.state.indexOfNavigation
              );
              let incrementModal = classArray[this.state.indexOfNavigation].id;
              this.setState(
                ({ classNavigation, ...restTop }) => ({
                  classNavigation: incrementModal,
                  ...restTop
                }),
                () => {
                  console.log(
                    "element Id being received after navigating",
                    classElement.id
                  );
                  console.log(
                    "classNavigation info after navigating",
                    this.state.classNavigation
                  );
                }
              );
            }
          );
        }
      }
    );
  };

  subOptionNavigation = childSubOption => {
    this.setState(
      ({
        newClassForm: {
          secondMenu: { internalNavigation, ...restSecondMenu },
          ...restNewClassForm
        },
        ...restTop
      }) => ({
        newClassForm: {
          secondMenu: { internalNavigation: childSubOption, ...restSecondMenu },
          ...restNewClassForm
        },
        ...restTop
      }),
      () => {
        console.log(
          "index of main array once navigating in the sub menu",
          this.state.indexOfNavigation
        );
        console.log(
          "classNavigation info after navigating in sub menus",
          this.state.classNavigation
        );
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    //here I change the format of the new class form object
    let classArray = [];
    for (let key in { ...this.state.newClassForm }) {
      classArray.push({
        id: key,
        config: this.state.newClassForm[key]
      });
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Create a new class?</h1>
        <button onClick={this.newClassHandler}>Go!!</button>
        {this.state.createNewClass
          ? this.state.newClassArray.map(cl =>
              cl.id.indexOf(this.state.classNavigation) !== -1 ? (
                <div
                  key={cl.id}
                  style={{
                    padding: "10px",
                    border: "1px solid black",
                    margin: "5px"
                  }}
                >
                  <Input
                    classArray={this.state.newClassArray}
                    classElement={cl}
                    elementType={cl.config.elementType}
                    title={cl.config.title}
                    navigationIncrement={() =>
                      this.inputMenuNavigationHandler(
                        this.state.newClassArray,
                        cl,
                        "increment"
                      )
                    }
                    navigationDecrement={() =>
                      this.inputMenuNavigationHandler(
                        this.state.newClassArray,
                        cl,
                        "decrement"
                      )
                    }
                    internalNavigationDisplay={
                      this.state.newClassForm.secondMenu.internalNavigation
                    }
                    toOption1={() => this.subOptionNavigation("subOption1")}
                    toOption2={() => this.subOptionNavigation("subOption2")}
                  />
                </div>
              ) : null
            )
          : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```